# Curl requests in pThread crashes after completion of request

Tags: c++, curl, cocos2d-x

I am having wired problem while using curl with pthread. I refered  official code at given [URL](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/multithread.html) . The code crashes if I add `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` or `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT`. There is also an interesting thing that this crash occurs, when my response is completely done. :(. I am wondering if somebody has gone through this. below is my code which I run from  scene of `cocos2dX`.

-Make sure that code runs, wait for 30 second to complete and app would crash. However if Timeout options are excluded this crash will not come. Below is code snippet causing problem.

```
static void *pull_one_url(void *url)
{
    CURL *curl;

    curl = curl_easy_init();

    //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); // will crash if enabled  just wait for 30 second to pass away
    //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30); // will crash if enabled  just wait for 30 second to pass away

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
    curl_easy_perform(curl); /* ignores error */
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    return NULL;
}

void mainTest()
{
    pthread_t tid[NUMT];
    int i;
    int error;

    /* Must initialize libcurl before any threads are started */
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

    std::cout<<"go go ";

    for(i=0; i< NUMT; i++)
    {
        error = pthread_create(&tid[i],
                               NULL, /* default attributes please */
                               pull_one_url,
                               (void *)urls[i]);
        if(0 != error)
            fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't run thread number %d, errno %d\n", i, error);
        else
            fprintf(stderr, "Thread %d, gets %s\n", i, urls[i]);
    }

    std::cout<<"come come ";
    /* now wait for all threads to terminate */
    for(i=0; i< NUMT; i++) {
        error = pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
        fprintf(stderr, "Thread %d terminated\n", i);
    }

}
```

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/multithread.html[Curl site reference](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/multithread.html)

Answer (score 0):

try CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL should fix the problem